# parsing of xml to mysql database

Tags: python, xml, django, xml-parsing, django-views

In my app,i am including a function called xml parsing.I am trying to data the data from an xml file and save it to mysql database.

I coded this with the help from google engine,but as required the data's are not saving in the database.I can run the app without any error.

Please see my codes below

views.py

```
def goodsdetails(request):
    path = "{0}shop.xml".format(settings.PROJECT_ROOT)
    xmlDoc = open(path, 'r')
    xmlDocData = xmlDoc.read()
    xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)

    for items in xmlDocTree.iter('item'):
        item_id = items[0].text
    customername = items[1].text
        itemname = items[2].text
        location = items[3].text
        rate = items[4].text        
        shop=Shop.objects.create(item_id=item_id,customername=customername,
            itemname=itemname,location=location,rate=rate)
        shop.save()


shops = Shop.objects.all()
    context={'shops':shops}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

I am using the above logic to save the data in database from xml file.I am not getting any error but it is not saving into database

Expected answers are most welcome.

**Update:**I updated the code,really the xml data gets saved in db,but while displaying the same i am getting the following Traceback

```
IntegrityError at /
(1062, "Duplicate entry '101' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Shop.objects.get` **loads** data from the database. You want to **create** data, which you do by just calling `Shop(item_id=item_id,customername=customername,            itemname=itemname,location=location,rate=rate)` and then `shop.save()`.

If you want to *update* the data, you need to do something like this:

```
shop = Shop.objects.get(tem_id=item_id)
shop.customername = customername
...etc...
shop.save()
```

Comment: Using Shop.objects.create() i did't it and checked but as above like it is not giving any error but not saving in db,any sugesstions are welcome

Comment: @MonkL: Then maybe you can update the question with the code you actually tried? Because the code in your question makes no attempt of creating data.

Comment: Hi i corrected the above error,but for every refresh the data gets dublicated in db,

Comment: @MonkL: Yes, this is expected. If you want to update existing objects you need to handle that as well. For that you need to use get, and then update the object and then save it.